# QMessageBox не изменяется шрифт, размер и тип

Tags: c++, qt4

Не могу изменить шрифт в QMessageBox.
Что делаю:
объявил в .h файле

```
 QMessageBox *qMessageBox;
```

.c файле в конструкторе делаю следующие

```
qMessageBox = new(QMessageBox);
id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont("/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf");
font = QFont(QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id).first());
font.setPointSize(8);
qMessageBox->setFont(font);
```

Вывожу сообщение :

```
    void StateBalanser::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    qMessageBox->information(this,"информация о состоянии","номер");
}
```

Когда вывожу сообщение вижу, что текст не изменился.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы вызываете статический метод, который создает новый экземпляр `QMessageBox`, ничего не знающий о настройках шрифта.

Сделайте вашему экземпляру `qMessageBox` метод `exec()` - получите желаемое

Comment: Весь парадокс в том, когда делаю метод 'exec()'  при вызове конструктора каждый раз происходит вызов 'qMessageBox'.

Comment: Экземпляр класса  qMessageBox нельзя "вызвать".

Comment: Не понял. Я добавлял в код 'qMessageBox->exec();
' и когда вызывается конструктор на экране появляется 'MessageBox'.

Comment: Вам надо ВМЕСТО information() вызывать exec()

Comment: я не вызываю information(). Вот код : '    qMessageBox = new(QMessageBox);

    id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont("/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf");

    font = QFont(QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id).first());

    font.setPointSize(8);

    qMessageBox->setFont(font);

    qMessageBox->exec();' Где  information()  ?